# Declaring variables in javascript functions

Tags: javascript, html

I have written the following code to validate logins. It will now only check one user ID and password. I want to create a string array to check IDs and passwords but when I try to declare a variable, the function `check` is reported as not defined.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Login page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 style="font-family:Comic Sans Ms;text-align="center";font-size:20pt color:#00FF00;>Simple Login Page</h1>
    <form name="login">
      Username<input type="text" name="userid"/>
      Password<input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
      <input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
      <input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
    </form>
    <script language="javascript">
      "use strict"
      function check(form)/*function to check userid & password*/
      {
        int a;
        a = 1;
        if(form.userid.value == "jscholl" && form.pswrd.value == "astronomy")
        {
          window.open("index.html");
        }
        else
        {
          alert("Error Password or Username")/*displays error message*/
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The language attribute for script elements was deprecated in [*HTML 4*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT) and removed in subsequent versions, so omit it. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is initialize the variable using

`var a = 1;` or 
`var a; a= 1`

NOTE: variables declared in a function can only be accessible by it self or other within its scope

Answer (score 1):

This line here

```
int a;
a = 1;
```

You just need to do `var a = 1` - By default, there is no type assertion in JS.